# Selenium cannot find input element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a bot which will log in to a certain website, and selenium just refuses to cooperate (I have successfully made the bot for another site, but somehow fail at this one).

I'm trying to find this object and send keys to it

```
<input type="text" class="form-textbox form-textbox-text" id="account_name_text_field" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-describedby="apple_id_field_label" spellcheck="false" ($focus)="appleIdFocusHandler()" ($keyup)="appleIdKeyupHandler()" ($blur)="appleIdBlurHandler()" placeholder="Apple ID" autofocus="">
```

I have already tried:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[type = 'text']")
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-textbox-text")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("account_name_field")
```

And selenium keeps saying there is no element.
I'm putting a sleep before the line so that the site has time to fully load. 
I'm still pretty sure it's some kind of newbie problem so sorry for that. Just couldn't find any tutorial which would work for me.

Comment: passing of classname and id maybe wrong:-                                                    
`username = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-textbox form-textbox-text")`
`username = driver.find_element_by_id("account_name_text_field")`                                      Please check id's.

Comment: Seems like `driver.find_element_by_id("account_name_field")` should be `driver.find_element_by_id("account_name_text_field")`.

Comment: Have you checked to see if maybe this is inside an iframe? If so, you will need to switch to that iframe before being able to find an element within it.

Comment: Thanks @Rkelley ! Your answer was correct. Just as i thought, my nooobness was uncovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So thanks to @RKelley I got what i needed. The issue was, I was present in the wrong iframe. To fix that, I ctrl+f in the site source searching for "iframe". I found this:

```
<iframe src="https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=e0b80c3bf78523bfe80974d320935bfa30add02e1bff88ec2166c6bd5a706c42&amp;font=sf" width="100%" height="100%" id="aid-auth-widget-iFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I switched to it by:

```
login_iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('aid-auth-widget-iFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(login_iframe)
```

Then I found my element by Id and everything works. Thanks guys!